# A polite substitution for "lamer"

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, politeness, pejorative-language

Is there a polite word that can be used to designate someone who didn't really understand what he or she was doing? Or, in general, someone who is intentionally ignorant of how things work. A "lamer" doesn't fit for being impolite, and seemingly harming some people's ears too much.

**Edit:** Another good definition is

> It distinguishes between people who
>   are ignorant by chance from those who
>   are ignorant by choice.

And it makes me think that there is no polite substitution just because the meaning itself being impolite and abusive. Right?

Comment: Do you want terms for someone "ignorant by change" or "ignorant by choice"? Pick one. :)

Comment: I can't give a specific word offhand, but I don't doubt there are several. I personally know pretty much how the internals of a car work, but I know plenty of people who drive perfectly well with no such knowledge. Some of them actively resist learning what goes on under the bonnet, and it doesn't automatically follow that such an attitude should always be refered to disparagingly.

Comment: I personally have been tripped up more than once in a lifetime working with computers. I might have once known how an application functioned internally, and used the app in such a way as to capitalise on that knowledge. If the app gets a complete rewrite, I may be in a worse position than if I'd just stuck to the 'dumb user' approach.

Comment: @Fumble: No offense, but your computer literacy probably isn't very on-topic.

Comment: @MrHen: I make these comments because I'm taking the question at face value. It asks for a non-derogatory term for someone who *doesn't understand* what they do. I assume they actually *do* it perfectly well - they're just not interested in how it works in detail. I'm reminding others that such an attitude can reasonably be understood, even valued. Most Answers seem to completely miss the point of the question.

Comment: @Fumble there is some nuance. Being ignorant in the area one never attend to, is not a shame - it's perfectly normal, we all are. But being intentionally ignorant where one is *trying to participate*, trying to teach others, while being not modest bot arrogant, is a shame. I feel that lamer more refers to that latter one, not just a newbie/one who don't care.

Comment: @Col Shrapnel: Well if you really *are* looking for a positive word to describe a negative quality, I'd better just delete my answer because it's not relevant. I thought you were quite happy with a person being ignorant of details so long as the job got done properly, and just wanted a word to describe someone like that in a positive way.

Comment: Personally I have no interest in suggesting words that hide the real meaning. If the quality you want to describe is bad, either so so or say nothing. Don't lie.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see no reason in deleting any answers for whatever reason. It's always a food for thoughts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wish I could. these guys from meta refuse to speak to anyone who isn't courteous enough.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Ok, well it's your question, so I'll leave my answer in if you like. I don't understand the reference to *those guys from meta* though. Surely you're not trying to find a polite way of telling the main 'experts' on this site that they don't know what they're doing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Novice?  Unaware of [whatever]?  **Edit:** A self-appointed expert?

The problem is that implying that someone *intentionally* ignorant of something is inherently discourteous.  All of the polite variants you'll find will be implying that the ignorance is unintentional.

Comment: Well you nailed it right before I realized it myself. So, there is no answer at all. Just to refine your definition: A novice who tries to teach others on the matter.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: A self-appointed expert, perhaps?

Comment: That's closest one (at least to my not-so-good feel for English)

Answer (score 7):

Shamelessly copied and pasted from NOAD:

> Someone who knows nothing about growing things might be called **ignorant** by a farmer who never went to high school but has spent his life in the fields. Although all of these adjectives refer to a lack of knowledge, ignorant refers to a lack of knowledge in general (: a foolish, ignorant person) or to a lack of knowledge of some particular subject (: ignorant of the fine points of financial management).
>
> A professor of art history might refer to someone who doesn't know how to look at a painting as **uneducated** or **untutored**, both of which refer to a lack of formal education in schools (: she was very bright but basically uneducated, and completely untutored in the fine arts).
>
> Someone who cannot read or write is **illiterate**, a term that may also denote a failure to display civility or cultivated behavior (: the professor routinely referred to his students as illiterate louts).
>
> Someone who is **unlettered** lacks a knowledge of fine literature (: a scientist who was highly trained but unlettered); it also implies being able to read and write, but with no skill in either of these areas.
>
> **Unlearned** is similar to ignorant in that it refers to a lack of learning in general or in a specific subject (: an unlearned man who managed to become a millionaire), but it does not carry the same negative connotations.
>
> **Uninformed** refers to a lack of definite information or data. For example, one can be highly intelligent and well educated but still uninformed about the latest developments in earthquake prediction.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be nice, you can say the person is a *[neophyte](http://www.merriam-webstercollegiate.com/dictionary/neophyte)*. Less polite would be *[philistine](http://www.merriam-webstercollegiate.com/dictionary/philistine)*, which MW defines as "one uninformed in a special area of knowledge." If this is a technology-related field, *[luddite](http://www.merriam-webstercollegiate.com/dictionary/luddite?show=0&t=1302025523)* might work (though it's not very nice, either). A more neutral way of saying "intentionally ignorant" might be

> exhibits a deliberate lack of sophistication about **_**.

**EDIT:** Understanding the question better now, I offer another option to describe someone who is arrogantly and intentionally ignorant yet insists on trying to instruct others.

> insists on [spreading *or* infecting others with] his deliberate lack of sophistication about **_**.

This assumes you're just looking for a polite way to describe the problem to third parties. You wouldn't say this to the person's face -- at least not if you expect to get along with him afterward. :)

Sorry so many words. I don't think there's a way to say this that is both concise *and* diplomatic.

Comment: Frankly, I don't *want* to be nice. More likely I forced to it %) However, lamer is not equal to neophyte. It's more likely an "arrogant neophyte".

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Well, "lamer" was unfamiliar to me before today (but I like it). Until I read your comments to Rhodri's answer, I didn't get the "arrogant" part. I've added another suggestion, though I'm still not sure I'm exactly hitting the right note.

Answer (score 1):

A polite way to say that a  person doesn't know something:

> [Person] is **not familiar with** [something].

For example,

> Mark is not familiar with Java programming.

Comment: It more fits for a newbie than a lamer.

Answer (score 1):

A few words that can mean "ignorant by choice" (with mixed amounts of tactfulness):

- unenthusiastic
- unmotivated
- lackadaisical
- bored
- resistant
- rebellious
- apathetic
- uninterested
- ennui
- listless
- passionless
- indifference

Answer (score 1):

my favorite is from "Shawshank Redemption" in which Andy accuses the warden of being obtuse.

Answer (score 1):

How about a "specialist"?

It's a long shot, but I myself try to avoid learning anything of certain areas, like music and politics. It's not an inherently negative practice (Although perhaps I shouldn't speak being an open practitioner ^.^). At least, it's not if you've read, or admire, your Sherlock Holmes.

If you don't remember, this was one of the features Watson found most remarkable about Mr. Holmes in *A Study in Scarlet*, in the second chapter, if you're interested. Despite his astonishing knowledge in several eclectic and esoteric areas, he remained ignorant of the primacy of the heliocentric theory in astronomy, and would have liked to remain so.

As I said, "specialist" is a long shot, but it's not insulting...I admit, that's mainly because it emphasises a hypothetical counterpoint for whatever intentional ignorance. Still, it seems to me that, sometimes, that is exactly what being polite is, ignoring the negative and hyping the positive.

Answer (score 0):

Although remaining judgmental and by no means polite, dispatching a `lamer` as an  [ignoramus](http://www.merriam-webstercollegiate.com/dictionary/ignoramus) superficially imparts authority in doing so.