# What is the synonym for the word `non-technical`?

Tags: synonyms

I want to say something like *Non-technical introduction to Python*. What word can replace *non-technical*?

I've fished out *un-technical* and *general* so far, but they don't really fit well.

Comment: "Layman's introduction", "Newbie's introduction", etc.  And of course, the ever-popular "Idiot's guide".

Comment: Ha! Jinx! Hot Licks!  (I'm pretty sure "Idiot's Guide..." is copyrighted by now)

Comment: Novice, neophyte, and maybe dilettante.  (I kind of like "dilettante", as it has a sort of subversive flavor to it.)

Comment: what does *fish out X so far* mean?

Comment: @Ooker it means "found"

Comment: @gt6989b ah I see. You have tried to fished out the sea, but only get the *un-technical* and *general* fish :)

Comment: @Ooker yes, indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say "A ***Layman's*** Introduction to Python"

The definition of "[layman](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/layman)", according to the Cambridge dictionary:

> someone who is not ​trained in or does not have a ​detailed ​knowledge of a ​particular ​subject

Comment: Please note this discussion of whether *layman* is gender-specific:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77401/non-gender-specific-alternative-to-layman

Comment: I guess you could argue that it should be "Layperson" but for a title that is not referring to a specific person, I still like "layman" for the (arguably), most common usage of the word.

Comment: Or just " lay".

Comment: Naive. As for gender, surely that would depend on the physical characteristics of the reptile in question?